# In this C code, why char should be assigned using a pointer and why string can be assigned directly to the variable?

Tags: c

I'm learning C and when i was learning `scanf` i stumbled upon this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    char firstLetter;

    printf("First letter? ");

    scanf("%c", &firstLetter);


    char firstName[20], lastName[20];


    printf("What's your name?");

    scanf(" %s %s", firstName, lastName);

    printf("Name: %s %s\n", firstName, lastName);

}
```

I'm trying to understand why is pointer to `firstLetter` should be used in first `scanf` and why it's different with strings?

Comment: @Pol Santha,  Code can even call `scanf("%c", firstName);` to assign `firstName[0]`.

Comment: More fundamental reason: In C if you want a function to change a variable and make the change visible after the function call, you must pass a pointer to the variable instead of the variable itself.

Answer (score 2):

When an array is passed to `scanf` it decays to a pointer to the first element. Bear in mind this pointer knows nothing about the size of the array, so it's best to use a width specifier to ensure `scanf` doesn't overflow the array's bounds, resulting in undefined behavior.

```
scanf(" %19s %19s", firstName, lastName);
```

Note, you should also always check the return value from `scanf` to ensure it succeeded in reading the expected number of values.

Comment: Good point about using a _width_.

Answer (score 1):

`char firstName[20]` is an array.

With `scanf(" %s", firstName);`, the array `firstName` is converted to the type and address of the array's first element (a `char *`) or the same as `scanf(" %s", &firstName[0]);`.

So both `scanf("%c", &firstLetter);` and `scanf(" %s", firstName);` receive an address as an argument.

The `"%c"` directs `scanf()` to assign 1 `char` at the specified address.

The `"%s"` directs `scanf()` to assign several `char` starting at the specified address.